# SIGSEGV error occurs when I sort the inner string of the word

Tags: c++, sorting

I am doing the coding challenge on Codewar which is about sorting the inner string in descending order.

Problem description:

For example:  "wait for me" -> "wiat for me"

The string will never be null and will never be empty.
It will contain only lowercase-letters and whitespaces.

My solution is that take every word and store them in the vector, perform sorting and return the new string. I have passed the example tests, but when I submit the solution, it shows that "Process exited prematurely with a SIGSEGV signal." I have googled this error and I find that it is usually related to illegal access of memory, like array out of bound error. Therefore, I have checked my code, but I can't find the problem, it seems that the loops haven't access something out of bound. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional> 
using namespace std;



char* sortTheInnerContent(const char* words, int length) {
  char *str = new char[length + 1];
  string tmp;
  vector<string> items;

 //take the word and store in vector
 for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
   if(words[i] != ' '){
     tmp += words[i];
   }
   if(words[i] == ' ' || i == length - 1){
     items.push_back(tmp);
     tmp.clear();
   }
 }

 //sort the inner string
 for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
   sort (items.at(i).begin() + 1, items.at(i).end() - 1, std::greater<int>
());
 }

 //create a new string
 for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
    if(i == items.size() - 1){
        tmp.append(items.at(i));
        tmp += '\0';
     }else{
        tmp.append(items.at(i));
        tmp.append(" ");
     }
 }

 strcpy(str, tmp.c_str());

 return str;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using char buffers/C strings and not `std::string`? Also, could you post an example of how you're calling it?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error, calling the function like `sortTheInnerContent("wait for me\0", strlen("wait for me\0"))` produces the expected output. Are you forgetting to null-terminate the string?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also can't reproduce the error locally, but it does occur when I submit to the Codewar's system.

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting. I'm unfamiliar with Codewar, but does that mean you can't change the function signature? If you can change it, I would _strongly_ suggest trying to use `std::string` in place of `char *`. If not, do they have a forum you can post on? Since neither of us can reproduce the issue locally, it might be an issue specific to Codewar?

Comment: @KelvinNg -- *//take the word and store in vector* -- Even when using `char *`, this should be no more than 10 (and I'm being generous) lines of C++ code.  First, use `std::istringstream` instead of that very dodgy `for` loop to extract each word into the vector.  That is no more than 3 lines of code.  Then call `sort` on the vector of strings for each string.  Then to append to a string, no more than another 3 lines of code to take the contents of the vector and create the new string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie--Thanks for your solution, I know that my code is too long as I'm not familiar with the built-in functions of C++ lol.But in terms of algorithm, I think it should be Okay and without logical errors.